# How to increase progress antd capacity

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design component `Progress`. I need to increase it capacity. For example, it should be filled in 500%. Now when number of `percent` increasing more than 100, it fills. How can I do this?

```
<Progress percent={percent} type="line" size="small" status="active" />;
```

It's how I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-winiec

You can update the percent by your total percent requirement dynamically

```
<Progress percent={25} format={percent => `${percent*5} %`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Progress type="line" steps={500} size="small" status="active"/>
```

But you must set the `percent` attribute between 0 and 100.
If it's not you must divide it to 5.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried `steps`, but component changing it style, and I don't need this.

Comment: Change the style

Comment: Check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dashboard-antd-4-17-3-forked-7x4je